# Pose mode and GRS all give me a scale cursor that doesn't do any thing

Tags: rigging

I'm currently following a tutorial to rig a character.

All goes well until I go to Pose Mode to see if my rig moves (I can do that before or after doing the automatic weight things, it changes nothing).

[image: Pose Mode]

What happens is most strange: I select a bone and press <kbd>G</kbd>. The usual box with the colour arrows appear, I try to grab and move one of them and it turns into a <kbd>><</kbd> like that.

[image: Cursor Change]

So far I've only seen that whilst scaling in edit mode and it does nothing, same with rotating. 
I verified I do not have any lock on location or rotation for the chosen bone or it's neighbours. I also dont have the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or snap to center turned on, I checked all I could in the manual and here and found nothing.
I've spent the afternoon on this and it's driving me nuts.
I haven't found anywhere on the net anyone who talked about a dead scale <kbd>><</kbd> cursor dragging and replacing the wheel and grab and scale box.

I am following the free rig the biker tutorial on Digital Tutors and so far so good, I checked everything. I'm nearing nervous breakdown.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you please add some images explaining your problem? Right now your question is hard to understand.

Comment: DONE here is a picture of pose mode, the G box at the ready, the next is what happens when I grab one of the handles and pull to the right. It happens for GRS in all direction and nothing ever moves I hope this helps https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihf730vbbl33ch8/Screen%20Shot%202016-11-21%20at%2023.12.34.png?dl=0             https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzfqa2obrdyihoa/Screen%20Shot%202016-11-21%20at%2023.13.04.png?dl=0                        there are two images links sorry I cant figure out how to post the image direct here

Comment: @mcc did you get anywhere with this? I've got exactly the same problem. :(

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your second screenshot, I'd suppose you've got `Manipulate Center Points` activated. While this is useful on multiple selected objects or bones, when bones are **not** connected, it leads to the behavior you describe in your Question. See the GIF below on how to deactivate this feature:

[image: Manipulate Center Points]

The purpose of this feature is to **Translate** objects by using **Rotate** or **Scale** functions. In your case, as the bone is already a child of another bone, Translation channels are automatically locked already. That's why nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try Alt , (Alt-comma) - worked for me. :)

What this does is get you out of 'Manipulate Centre Point' mode:

[image]